# Python Selenium noarch RPM build failure

Tags: python, selenium, rpm

Attempting to build Python Selenium noarch rpm from downloaded selenium-2.20.0.tar.gz
All necessary Python requirements are installed and working, using command:

```
python setup.py bdist --format=rpm
```

RPMBuild fails with error message:

```
Arch dependent binaries in noarch package
error: command 'rpmbuild' failed with exit status 1
```

Have tried following the suggestion of adding an additiional %define to the selenium.SPEC file, found under `build/bdist.linux-i686/rpm/SPECS/selenium.spec`

```
%define _binaries_in_noarch_packages_terminate_build 0
```

Unfortunately when i re-run the RPM build, the change is not picked up and the contents of the SPEC file after the build seem to have re-verted as the newly added %define is no longer present?!

Any suggestions welcome please..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changes to `selenium.spec` weren't persisting as the spec file is automatically generated from content mostly from within `setup.py`

Two solutions were found:

1) Download most recent version of `selenium-2.20.0.tar.gz` from `http://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium/` to target machine, tar extract and run:

> python setup.py install

2) Install python pip, then use pip to dowload and install the latest selenium in an automated fashion with the command:

> pip install -U selenium

As yet i have not found the exact content that can be added to setup.py that will add the necessary RPM build define to the `selenium.spec` file for creating an installation RPM..

Answer (score 0):

For the future if anyone comes across this

```
python setup.py bdist_rpm --force-arch x86_64
```

Worked for me